# Взаимодействие Android с сайтом.

Tags: android

Нужно написать сайт и приложение Android на диплом. Скажите, с помощью чего взаимодействует приложение с сайтом? 
Лучше и сайт и приложение писать с помошью SQLite? Или можно сайт с помощью MySQL? 
Буду рада ссылкам. Спасибо.

Comment: Нужно написать сайт типо интернет-магазина, и следовательно приложение на эту же  тему.

Comment: чтобы в приложении можно было выбирать товар, просматривать его характеристики, просматривать корзину, отправлять заказ на сервер. Я пока не совсем в этом всём разбираюсь, по-этому мне необходима помощь, в виде информации.

Comment: @Наташенька, меня вдохновляет твое рвение к наукам =) я бы тебе уже 5ть поставил за диплом

Comment: @Gorets я чувствую ты бы не прочь быть и экзаменатором уже ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не важно какую БД вы будете использовать на сайте. Т.к. интерпретатор, будь то PHP или любой другой, все равно будет той "прослойкой" между данными и вашим телефоном. Поэтому вполне логично воспользоваться PHP + MySQL для сайта, так как информации по этим двум понятиям очень и очень много, легко разобраться, легко о них написать в дипломе. Так же легко можно написать простенький сайтик с теми же возможностями, как у приложения, а, может, и больше.

Для Андроида, вам понадобится ряд классов (например [такой](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/)), которые позволяют делать `GET` и `POST` запросы, а так же принимать от них данные. Данные в свою очередь вы будете выдавать (с помощью PHP) в удобном для вас виде (JSON, XML, CSV), главное чтобы телефон умел правильно их интерпретировать (т.е. иметь соответствующий парсер), а скрипт формировать.

Для получения данных, вы можете использовать обычный `GET` запрос, который будет обрабатываться специальным для этого скриптом, например, запрос может выглядеть так:

```
/androidapprequest.php?func=getprodinfo&prod_id=755&format=json
```

Т.е. ваш скрипт `androidapprequest.php` выдаст вам информацию о продукте с индексом 755, в формате JSON. Аналогично вы можете придумывать функции, и обрабатывать их на стороне сервера, выдавая только запрошенные данные.

Таким же образом вы затем сможете расширить функционал, добавив функции не только чтения, но и добавления данных.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! + 1

Answer (score 2):

Сайт пишется на чем угодно, главное, чтобы морда генерировалась на HTML и предпочтительно чтобы данные лежали в какой нить SQL базе
Клиентское Android приложение можно написать тремя способами:

1. Написав парсер (анализатор-разборщик) HTML ответов сервера (сайта) которые далее будут транслироваться в некие вьюшки Android клиента. Это самый хреновый способ, поскольку любое форматирование/редизайн сайта приведут к неработоспособности клиента - просто потому, что парсер перестанет понимать ответ сервера.
2. Тупо отображать на Android клиенте ответы сервера через `WebView` - ну это потянет на троечку.
3. Или самый лучший способ (гарантированная 5-ка в дипломе): так чтобы сайт имел вторую дверь (специальный порт или специальный запрос) через которую он будет сообщать клиенту что там у него происходит в морде. Предпочтительно, чтобы ответы сайта были на XML или JSon - тогда анализатор на стороне клиента написать гораздо проще.

Возьмите для примера скажем какой-нибудь известный сайт - да все тот же Facebook и как работает его Android клиент. По сути Facebook принимает и отвечает на запросы клиента используя некую разновидность XML (FBML) + SQL - ну разве что обернутую в [некий API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/) для удобства девелопера.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что не все хостеры поддерживают `SQLite` и если честно в свое время я этому был удивлен!

Так что с точки зрения профессионального подхода разработки конкретно сайта, используйте `MySQL`.

**UPD**: По поводу `SQLite` - из горького опыта)

Comment: смысл вообще рассуждать про SQLite вне андроида? какая разница кто его из провайдеров поддерживает? SQLite используют только как бд для мобильного устройства

Comment: @Gorets мой ответ был дан исключительно отталкиваясь из вопроса ТС'а а конкретно вот на этот вопрос

>Лучше и сайт и приложение писать с помошью SQLite?

К этому и сводился ответ что сайт с использованием SQLite в качестве БД не везде будет работать!

Comment: все равно глупо =) если отталкивается от вопроса - так он особо смысловой нагрузки не несет вообще, кто это сайты пишет на SQLite?
И почему это " сайт с использованием SQLite в качестве БД не везде буде работать!" ? Какая разница мне на какой бд у тебя сайт "написан"? Если у тебя данные хранятся в SQLite и все работает, то мой браузер твою бд даже не заметит =)

Comment: В том то и дело что если! Бессмысленный спор. Не везде будет работать - это значит что не на всех хостингах! Читать нужно внимательно все, а не подняв перья спорить непонятно о чем!

Answer (score 0):

Приложение на Android-телефоне и сайт на удаленном сервере - это разные вещи.

Сайт обычно пишут с помощью MySQL, а приложение (если требуются манипуляции с данными - словари там всякие и т.п.) - с помощью SQLite.

Если все взаимодействие сводится к просмотру страниц сайта, то достаточно стандартных компонентов типа WebView. Если что-то более сложное, то можно использовать какой-то REST API или вроде.